# Changing the appearance of an NSPopUpButtonCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview

I have a custom `NSTableView` subclass that handles selection on its own. The default behavior for a `NSPopUpButtonCell` when a row is selected is to change the color of its text and the little arrows to white, like so:

[image: Normal selected NSPopUpButton behavior]

I need to imitate this behavior. I have tried setting the attributed string of the menu items with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary
                            dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            [NSFont systemFontOfSize: [NSFont systemFontSize]],
                            NSFontAttributeName, nil];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [(NSPopUpButtonCell*)aCell numberOfItems]; i++) {
    NSMenuItem *item = [(NSPopUpButtonCell*)aCell itemAtIndex:i];

    NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
                              initWithString:[item title]
                              attributes:attributes];

    [item setAttributedTitle:as];
}
```

This changes the color of the text, but then it stays white on each of the menu items when you pop open the menu. It also does not change the color of the little arrows next to the text. Setting the `attributedTitle` of the `NSPopUpButtonCell` directly does not seem to have any effect.

I was really hoping that there would just be some sort of flag somewhere I could flip, like `[aCell isSelectedInTableView:YES]` or something, but if it exists I can't seem to figure out what it would be. How does the `NSTableView` accomplish this effect?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Hello from the end of 2020, any luck with that :D